# future value calculation not returning expected result

Tags: php, excel, function, financial

have the following FV function

```
private static function fv($r,$n,$p,$pv=0)
{
    $sum = $pv;
    for ( $i=0;$i<$n;$i++ ) {
     $sum += ($sum * $r) + $p;
    }
    return $sum;
}
```

These are the values I'm passing in:

0.0067
444
1834.58

This is the value I'm expecting from my deskcheck: 4983453.613
This is what I'm getting from my method: 5036155.12

Driving me nuts. I've tried a bunch of other functions on-line; none of them work!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to get?

Comment: @Mob: future value of a retirement fund...

Comment: I'm guessing r = interest rate, n = number of periods, and pv = present value, but what's p?

Comment: could it be that each time you multiply and add it to the sum you are getting a rounding error because when you do it on a calculator it doesnt round as heavily? maybe you should echo the sum each time it loops through and see if there is a rounding error.

Comment: @jprofitt p = present monthly value

Comment: thanks to all who helped out and gave time to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a rounding error, but only in so far as `0.0067` is not precise enough.

For `$r = 0.0067` I get the same result as your are getting.

For `$r = 0.00666666666666666666666` I get the result you want.

I suggest you pass in `$r = 1 / 150` for the best possible precision.

Comment: you're right. it is a rounding error. Just tested it right now and I get the right value. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran this through an Excel spreadsheet (set cell A1 to 0, set cell A2 to `=A1 + (A1*0.0067) + 1834.58`, copy down to A445 (representing 444 iterations starting from 0). The final iteration comes up with 5036155.12 as you say your function does.

How are you calculating the 4983453.613 you say you are expecting? Have you double checked your method there? I don't get that at any stage.

The first three iterations come out as:

```
1834.58
3681.451686
5540.697412
```

and the final three as:

```
4965710.242
5000815.08
5036155.122
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private static function fv($r=0,$n=0,$pv=0)
{

    for ( $i=0;$i<$n;$i++ ) {
        $pv+=($pv*$r);
    }
    return $pv;
}

echo fv(0.0067,444,1834.58);
```

A little tidying up and the above should do the trick.. $p was not set at any time, because of your scoping, you can repurpose $pv within the function without having to define $sum.